# ARcore - Can't Rotate Model without using TransformableNode

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm creating a AR application, but one of my models is in the wrong orientation.

I need it to rotate but no allowing the user to rotate it by touch.
Once loaded it has to remain in the same orientation.

I tried the code below and TransformableNode.

```
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
           if (imageName.equals("fox")){
               anchorNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new 
   Vector3(0f, 0, 1f), 180f));
           }else
               anchorNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new 
   Vector3(1f, 0, 0f), -10f));
           anchorNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
           arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().onAddChild(anchorNode);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code code:

```
// Imaginary anchor – example 1
float[] position = { 0, 0, -0.5 };
float[] rotation = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
Anchor anchor = session.createAnchor(new Pose(position, rotation));

// Imaginary anchor – example 2
Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();

///////////////////////////////////////////////

AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

// 180 Degrees CCW
Quaternion rotation180 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), 180); 
//  10 Degrees CW
Quaternion rotation010 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), -10); 

TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
node.setParent(anchorNode);
node.select();

if (imageName.equals("fox")) {
    node.setLocalRotation(rotation180);
    Node foxxy = new Node();
    foxxy.setParent(node);
    foxxy.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
} else {
    node.setLocalRotation(rotation010);
    Node notFox = new Node();
    notFox.setParent(node);
    notFox.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
}

arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().onAddChild(node);
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that code will make the model transformable by touch on the app.

i want a way that makes the model stay in the rotation I gave it in the code no matter what

Comment: And tried and everytime i touch the screen the app crashes
With this error: 
TransformableNode must have an AnchorNode as a parent.

Comment: I can't entirely understand what the issue is. Could you capture a video and share it here?